# UDP clients pool sending but not receiving

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I am creating an udp client pool. The servers will be some other applications running in different computers, and they are suppoused to be alive from beginning. Using a configurable file (not important to problem in example so not included) one to several clients are created so they connect to those servers (1 to 1 relation) in a bidirectional way, sending and receiving.

Sending can be sync because it uses small messages and blocking there in not a problem, but receiving must be async, because answerback can arrive much later after sending.

In my test with only one sockect, it is able to send, but it is not receiving anything at all.

Q1: Where is the problem and how to fix it?

Q2: I also wonder if the use of iterators from `std::vector` in the async calls can be problematic at the time new connections are pushed into vector due to its rearangment in memory. This may be a problem?

Q3: I really does not understand why in all examples sender and receiver endpoints (endpoint1 and endpoint2 in example `struct Socket`) are different, couldn't they be the same?

My code is next:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class Pool
{
    struct Socket {
        std::string id;
        udp::socket socket;
        udp::endpoint endpoint1;
        udp::endpoint endpoint2;
        enum { max_length = 1024 };
        std::array<char, max_length> data;
    };

public:
    void create(const std::string& id, const std::string& host, const std::string& port)
    {
        udp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        sockets.emplace_back(Socket{ id, udp::socket{io_context, udp::v4()}, *resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), host, port).begin() });

        receive(id);
    }

    void send(const std::string& id, const std::string& msg)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(), [&](auto& socket) { return id == socket.id; });
        if (it == sockets.end()) return;

        it->data = std::array<char, Socket::max_length>{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
        auto bytes = it->socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(it->data, 5), it->endpoint1);
    }

    void receive(const std::string& id)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(), [&](auto& socket) { return id == socket.id; });
        if (it == sockets.end()) return;

        it->socket.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(it->data, Socket::max_length),
            it->endpoint2,
            [this, id](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes) {
                if (!error && bytes)
                    bool ok = true;//Call to whatever function
                receive(id);
            }
        );
    }

    void poll()
    {
        io_context.poll();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    std::vector<Socket> sockets;
};

int main()
{
    Pool clients;
    clients.create("ID", "localhost", "55000");

    while (true) {
        clients.poll();
        clients.send("ID", "x");
        Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: UDP and bidirectional ?

Comment: Maybe not the best word for udp network stuff... I mean they are going to send and receive using the same socket.

Comment: you cannot use many udp clients in the same machine

Comment: They are not so much, maybe we are talking of a number between 3 and 10.

Comment: yes only one client is allowed to listen on an udp server

Comment: There are several udp servers outside my code, running in different PC's. Each of my clients shall connect to one and only one of those servers, in a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: When the peers reply, what endpoint do they address the reply to?

Comment: @sehe They reply to endpoint2. Do you mean that this is why there are 2 endpoints per each socket?

Comment: How can they reply to "endpoint2"? You didn't specify the code for the remote servers at all, and not only do they run in another process, they're also on different machines. It seems to me that "endpoint2" is a variable name that only means something in context.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to server code, they are just a specification requirement. For developing I am testing in only one computer using an open UDP server application, and I hope those results can be extrapolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Where is the problem and how to fix it?

You don't really bind to any port, and then you have multiple sockets all receiving unbound udp packets. Likely they're simply competing and something gets lost in the confusion.

> Q2: can std::vector be problematic

Yes. Use a `std::deque` (stable iterator/references as long as you only push/pop at either end). Otherwise, consider a `std::list` or other node-based container.

In your case `map<id, socket>` seems more intuitive.

Actually, `map<endpoint, peer>` would be a lot more intuitive. Or... you could do without the peers entirely.

> Q3: I really does not understand why in all examples sender and
> receiver endpoints (endpoint1 and endpoint2 in example struct Socket)
> are different, couldn't they be the same?

Yeah, they could be "the same" if you don't care about overwriting the original endpoint you had sent to.

---

Here's my simplified take. As others have said, it's not possible/useful to have many UDP sockets "listening" on the same endpoint. That is, provided that you even bound to an endpoint.

So my sample uses a single `_socket` with local endpoint :8765.

It can connect to many client endpoints - I chose to replace the id string with the endpoint itself for simplicity. Feel free to add a `map<string, endpoint>` for some translation.

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93050b6d87d43bf1)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Pool {
  public:
    using Message = std::array<char, 1024>;
    using Peers   = std::set<udp::endpoint>;
    using Id      = udp::endpoint;

    Pool() { receive_loop(); }

    Id create(const std::string& host, const std::string& port)
    {
        auto ep = *udp::resolver(_io).resolve(udp::v4(), host, port).begin();
        /*auto [it,ok] =*/_peers.emplace(ep);
        return ep;
    }

    void send(Id id, const std::string& msg)
    {
        /*auto bytes =*/
        _socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg), id);
    }

    void receive_loop()
    {
        _socket.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(_incoming), _incoming_ep,
            [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes) {
                if (!error && bytes)
                {
                    if (_peers.contains(_incoming_ep)) {
                        std::cout << "Received: "
                                  << std::quoted(std::string_view(
                                         _incoming.data(), bytes))
                                  << " from " << _incoming_ep << "\n";
                    } else {
                        std::cout << "Ignoring message from  unknown peer "
                                  << _incoming_ep << "\n";
                    }
                }
                receive_loop();
            });
    }

    void poll() { _io.poll(); }

  private:
    boost::asio::io_context _io;
    udp::socket             _socket{_io, udp::endpoint{udp::v4(), 8765}};
    Message                 _incoming;
    udp::endpoint           _incoming_ep;
    Peers                   _peers;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Pool pool;

    std::vector<Pool::Id> peers;

    for (auto port : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        peers.push_back(pool.create("localhost", port));
    }

    int message_number = 0;
    while (peers.size()) {
        pool.poll();

        auto id = peers.at(rand() % peers.size());
        pool.send(id, "Message #" + std::to_string(++message_number) + "\n");

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

Live on my machine with some remotes simulated like

```
sort -R /etc/dictionaries-common/words | while read word; do sleep 5; echo "$word"; done | netcat -u -l -p 8787 -w 1000
```

Also sending bogus messages from an "other" endpoint to simulate stray/unknown messages.

[image]

Comment: Cool! thank you for clarifying me all those udp concepts. I am going to abuse of your acknoledgment if you don't mind: It is necessery to set my port number (the 8765) or it would be valid if I just let the OS to automatically assign it a free one? I guess that this can be done using `udp::socket _socket{io_context, udp::v4()};` in private variable.

Comment: Ephemeral ports are fine as well. It's just a little less natural to communicate the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for teaching me. You could start some kind of consulting firm or similar, you might name it "Better Call Sehe" ;-)  (it's a Breaking Bad show joke, in case you haven´t wathed it)

Comment: Haha. Cheers. I think the meme predates BB? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul I think it's even in Pulp Fiction?